# Best-practice wise, how do I create a lazy-loading user entity in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm fetching user data from a web-based API, and I'd like to avoid fetching data and therefore making HTTP requests if I never need that data. I was thinking of creating a `User` class that takes a `$userID` in its constructor, and simply stores it. *If* at some point in time any getter method like `getUserName()` is called, it would make the call and fetch the data from the API.

Now, I created a service that's supposed to do all the API work. How would I go about connecting this `APIWrapper` service to my `User` entity class? I read that it's considered bad style to depend on the service container in an entity class. If this was a generally preferred solution, I would just have the `User` class depend on the service container and call the `APIWrapper` service, pass the `User` object by reference and have the service fill in everything that's fetched from the API. But how could I do this without having the `User` class depend on the service container?

I was hoping to be able to use it like this:

```
$user1 = new User(1234);
$user2 = new User(2345);
echo $user2->getName();
```

It would only fetch user2's name from the API, and do nothing with user1. That way, I could also easily implement caching so I don't even have to query the API at all.

So. What's considered to be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If the user is authenticating *and initially registering* with a third-party service, you should probably just get that info right when they sign up. How many users do you expect to have who will never need to provide their basic account info?

It is indeed bad practice to inject services into an Entity, as an Entity's purpose is nothing more than to contain an object and its data. You should use a `UserProvider` for fetching the user data for an existing user, as described in various sets of guidelines for integrating the FOSUserBundle and the FOSFacebookBundle.

Now, when you do a Google search for integrating those two bundles, or when you ask around, you're going to be pointed to a paid screencast that costs $15. If you're really committed to Symfony as a framework for your projects, it may be worth your money to see how the people that build Symfony things think. If you are willing to deal with some pulling out of your own hair, you can dig deeper into the search results, and look at resources like this gist: https://gist.github.com/iBet7o/5215066.

Your exact implementation will depend on the bundles you're using, but in general, what your code should end up looking like is this:

```
function getName() {
    if($this->name == '') {
        return $this->getSignupProvider()->getUserinfo(); // or maybe just getProvider()
    }
    return $this->name;
}
```

Comment: My app is interacting with a foreign API; I won't get notified or anything when someone signs up. It's not like they won't need to provide their basic account info, it's about not having to fetch the data from the API if it's not necessary. For example, I might end up with an array of users in a group or something, and then I'd print the names of all users that are moderators of the group. I wouldn't need to know anything about the other users, so I wouldn't have to fetch their data from the API. Anyway, thanks for answering, I'll look into that gist and try to work something out.